# JSX/React interpolation/syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx, string-interpolation

I'm using map() to iterarate an array of objects to render them on my app. I have imported audio files and I would like to reference them for the `src` attribute when mapping. `src={x.sound}` evaluates to just text, as it should. How can I achieve something like this `src={{x.sound}} => src={boom}` so that the `src`would actually be a valid path after iteratively rendering?

Thank you!

```
import boom from "./sound/boom.ogg";

const data = [
  {
    key: "Q",
    keyCode: 81,
    sound: "boom",
  },
];

const buttons = () =>
  data.map((x) => (
    <div
      onClick={this.clickHandle}
      id={x.sound}
      className="drum-pad"
      key={x.key}
    >
      {x.key}
      <audio
        id={x.key}
        key={x.key}
        src={x.sound}
        className="clip"
        controls
      ></audio>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: Did you try using the require syntax?

Comment: I guess, just using you can add the imported `boom` in data object, and then use that audio object

Comment: @luckongas I haven't. Do you mean RequireJS module loader? I'm learning React and trying to refrain at the moment from any extras.

Comment: @Swaraj Gandhi I'm afraid I don't follow you here. Could you give a sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are passing string ('boom') to the audio tag's source property. For JS/React it is not implied to look up if the current scope's variables contain one named after a particular string.

There are 2 ways you could make this work.

1. You can change your data object's sound property to reference the imported sound object (instead of string)

```
import boom from './sound/boom.ogg';

const data = [
  {
    key: 'Q',
    keyCode: 81,
    sound: boom,
  },
];
```

2. If you are serving your static files in 'public' folder on the server, you could put your audio file there as well. And then get it using a relative path.

```
const data = [
  {
    key: 'Q',
    keyCode: 81,
    sound: './boom.ogg',
  },
];
```